# Out Of Memory when using Entity Framework with large database (600+ entities)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I'm using Entity Framework 5 with large database with 600+ tables (haven't counted stored procedure and views yet). After few start and running using Visual Studio 2012 I get Out of Memory error when trying to Update my Model.EDMX file (using right click Update from Database) or simply while trying to compile.

Quick google search says many people faced similar problem and someone in one forum suggested to use multiple EDMX files to avoid this. 
(link http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/b4ce1494-a0b4-42c6-af56-4ecbfeb83e29)

My question is 
1) Is there any way I can avoid this error and use large number of tables without trouble with EF? 
2) Is Entity Framework model is right ORM for me for large enterprise database? If not, can someone suggest me good one?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you want an answer to both questions you should post them separatedly.

Comment: When the upating fails with the "Out of Memory" error does the Visual Studio process actualy have available memory? Make sure that you have enough memory in your development machine. It might just be that updating the database objects requires much more resources than just adding them. See my answer below.

Comment: On my development laptop I'm not running anything else other then Visual Studio 2012 and this sample application. The task bar shows no alarming stats

Comment: Was looking more on various forums and found that breaking up Models in various part is only solution if you want to go with EF. now i have to look how to work on multiple entity models.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question.

I have found that updating the Entity Framework does not seem to work reliably in all cases.

Have you tried deleting all the objects in the model and inserting them again? It may be an acceptable workaround.

Comment: I tried several times by deleting the model. It works for few times (debugging/compiling) and then it stops.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend spending some time looking into nHibernate. It's not as user friendly in terms as UI than Entity Framework but that should be an advantage for you if you are dealing with a large number of tables.

http://nhforge.org/Default.aspx

Also, you're aware that you don't have to map all of the tables in your Entity model? You can just bring in the ones you need. I'm assuming that you don't need all 600 tables for what you're doing.